# Python terminal closes when importing BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm, python-import

I have a simple python program, that is supposed to scrape some information from the internet and do stuff with it. When I run the code in **PyCharm (IDE)** it works fine, but when I run it directly it doesn't work **(Right-click -> Open with -> Python)**. In order to find the error I put several input statements in the code, as such:

```
from random import choice
input(1)
import webbrowser as web
input(2)
from time import sleep
input(3)
import pyautogui as pg
input(4)
from platform import system
input(5)  # It closes after this.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
input(6)
import requests
input(7)
```

It all seems to work fine until **5**. I press enter then the terminal instantly closes **without any error messages**. So there must be something wrong when I **import BeautifulSoup from bs4**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Why does the python terminal close when executing the import statement? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to an exception that is terminating the process. I had the same problem a while ago and it was solved by installing the package.

Are you sure you have `bs4` installed? Try running `pip install bs4` to make sure it is installed.

Comment: Yeah I managed to solve the problem. Before I ran `pip install bs4` inside of Pycharm's terminal and that was the problem. Now that I ran it in the command prompt it all seems to work.